# Jtds Driver connection successful using ip but not with name using with android

Tags: java, android, jtds

I am trying to connect to a msql server using jtds driver 
my connection string is like this

```
    jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.0.44:1433/foodserv;TDS=8.0
```

but if i change it to

```
     jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://jagath-pc:1433/foodserv;TDS=8.0
```

Then it do not connect and gives SQLexception
Using the same name when i am connecting using my PC it is connecting OK, means there is no 
conflict with the server name

i get exception like this

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'Unable to resolve host "jagath-pc":
 No address associated with hostname'.
```

Comment: The `Exception` is quite clear: He can not resolve the host name. Is DNS working? Can you resolve other host names? So in the first place this is a problem with your network setup.

Comment: but conn string is working fine with ip address ,also with the same name when i am trying to connect using pc(windows) to sql server the name is working fine

Comment: Your problem is that your android device cannot resolve the name. Period. You have to solve this problem first.

Comment: @uwe plonus Thanks for such a fast reply. Any idea about it how to resolve that. or check that.what period means here ?

Comment: @uwe plonus : Thanks i got it right now  The jagath-PC is binded on IPV6 .thats why it was not detecting.